# Java: cómo usar else if

Tags: java

como están?

Tengo un trabajo práctico para la facultad en el cual necesito de su ayuda ya que estoy intentando encontrar el error y no logro hacerlo. Tengo un sistema de productos, precios y stock en el cual se debe calcular el precio final a través de ciertas condiciones, por lo que una de ellas es que si el producto es promocional no se le debería sumar la ganancia, entonces mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class Producto {

private String nombre;
private double precio;
private int stock;
private boolean esPromocional;


public Producto(String nombre, int precio, int stock, boolean esPromocional) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.esPromocional = esPromocional;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;  
}

public double getPrecio() {
    double ganancia = precio*20/100;
    if(stock >= 100 && precio < 1500)  {
    ganancia = (precio * 15/100);
    } else if (stock < 50) 
    {
    ganancia = (precio*15/100);
    } else if (esPromocional == true) {
    ganancia = 0.0;
    }
    double iva = (precio*21/100);
    return (precio + ganancia + iva);   
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public boolean getesPromocional() {
    return esPromocional;   
}
}
```

¿Dónde puede ser que este el error? ¿Puede ser la lógica de mi código?

Desde ya, les agradezco!
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que tienes la comprobación de `esPromocional == true` metida en un `else if`! Cuando enlazas `if` con `else if` o incluso `else` al final, tan solo una de las opciones se va a ejecutar, vayamos paso a paso:

```java
public double getPrecio() {
    double ganancia = precio*20/100;
    if(stock >= 100 && precio < 1500)  { // Si esto se cumple, ya no entrará al if de la promoción
    ganancia = (precio * 15/100);
    } else if (stock < 50) // Igualmente, si esto se cumple, tampoco entrará
    {
    ganancia = (precio*15/100);
    } else if (esPromocional == true) { 
    // La única manera de que entre aquí, es que no se cumpla
    // ninguna de las anteriores comprobaciones!!
    ganancia = 0.0;
    } 
    double iva = (precio*21/100);
    return (precio + ganancia + iva);   
}
```

Como ves, el `else if` nos permite asegurarnos de que *solo **una*** condición se cumple! Entonces, tenemos dos opciones, asignar valor a `ganancia` solo si no es promocional (tendríamos que comprobarlo para todos los `if`), o como haces tu, comprobar que es promocional y poner la ganancia a 0.

Personalmente, prefiero no asignar un valor si no lo voy a necesitar, así que la opción que mas me gusta es esta:

```java
public double getPrecio() {
    double ganancia = 0;
    if (esPromocional) { // Cuando la variable a comparar es un boolean no hace falta la igualdad
    // Cuando haces esPromocional == true, estás obteniendo un true
    // pero si esPromocional es true... claro que es == true, nos lo ahorramos 
        if (stock >= 100 && precio < 1500) {
            ganancia = (precio * 15/100);
        } else if (stock < 50) {
            ganancia = (precio*15/100);
        }
    }
    double iva = (precio*21/100);
    return (precio + ganancia + iva);   
}
```

Te he dejado comentarios en el código, pero basicamente, se trata de dejar ganancia a 0 y asignarla SOLO si no es promocional. Tal como lo haces tú, simplemente tendrías que quitar el `else` de tu `else if`, pero eso hace que sea más difícil de seguir el flujo, porque para qué estás asignando una variable para luego volver a dejarla a 0? Así de esta manera, lo primero que ves es que se comprueba que es promocional y ya no se asigna.

Cualquier duda, aquí estamos.

Answer (score -4):

Has creado la clase adecuadamente, pero ahora deberás crear otro archivo java en el cual tendrás un public static void main. Desde ahí crearás una instancia y comenzarás a trabajar con ella. He probado tu código de la manera en la que menciono y me ha funcionado adecuadamente.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Sí, ya tengo creadas las clases Inventario y Aplicación (en la que está el main). Lo que sí no me estaría funcionando el condicional booleano ya que me da el mismo resultado todos los productos, cuando los que son Promocionales deberían tener el precio final sin ganancia.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: No corresponde para nada a lo que están preguntado.